# SQL Query to stop displaying rows X hours after datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running this query in PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT * from integra_status WHERE type <> 'Maintenance' AND category = '".$result["sequence"]."' AND (status = 'Open' OR status = 'Resolved') ";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
        while($StatusRecords=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            echo '<br><strong>'.stripslashes($StatusRecords["title"]).'</strong><br><br>';
            echo stripslashes($StatusRecords["description"]).'<br>';
            echo '<strong>Date Added:</strong> '.$opendate2.'<br>';
            echo '<br><hr />';
        }
    }
```

How can i stop the row from displaying if the status = 'Resolved' and it has been 24 hours since the datetime in the `status_closed` column

Comment: Just add that as a condition to your query

Comment: `where status_closed > (now() - interval 24 hour)`?

Comment: i tried adding in my query (where status_closed < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) but that wasnt display all records

Comment: if the status = 'Open' then status_closed does not exist

Comment: Just change `(status = 'Open' OR status = 'Resolved')` to `(status = 'Open' OR (status = 'Resolved' AND status_closed < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM integra_status 
WHERE type <> 'Maintenance' AND category = '".$result["sequence"]."' AND ( status = 'Open' OR (status = 'Resolved' AND status_closed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)))
```

Depends on how you store your date, assuming DATETIME or TIMESTAMP

*EDIT* - 
Reversed less than operator to greater than to retrieve records that have only occurred from 24 hours ago upto now. As opposed from 24 hours ago or older.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * from integra_status WHERE type <> 'Maintenance' AND category = '".$result["sequence"]."' AND status = 'Open' AND status != 'Resolved'";
```

Comment: i want to display the rows where status = 'Resolved' but only for 24 hours after the status_closed column